# JMeter throughput drops when hitting Amazon ELB

Tags: rest, jmeter, amazon-elb

I am hosting a web application on Amazon's AWS Servers. I am currently in the process of load testing the application with JMeter. My main problem seems to be that when I go through an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) to hit the Amazon server's rather than hitting the servers directly - I seem to hit a cap in my throughput.

If I hit my web application directly - for each server I am able to achieve a throughput of 50 RPS per server.

If I hit my web application via Amazon's ELB - I am only able to achieve a max throughput of 50 RPS (total)

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced similar behavior when load testing using Jmeter via Amazon's ELB.

For more context my web application is a REST application which allows users to download content (~150 kb) via HTTP requests.

I am running Jmeter with the following flag "-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0" and running it with 10 threads. I have tried running these tests with multiple clients on different machines.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Load balancers may be tricky to test as they may have different mechanisms of orchestrating traffic depending on origin. The most commonly used approach to distinguish origin of the request and redirect it to the same host, which served previous request is a cookie. You can look into [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to correctly manipulate your cookies and make sure than you have different ones for each testing thread or thread group (depending on your use case). Another flaky area is origin host IP. You may require to bind each testing thread to different IP address in order to hit different servers behind the load balancer. There can be also some issues with DNS in regards to Amazon LBs. useful guide on [how to test Amazon ELBs](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/94060-testing-amazon-elbs)

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause would be DNS caching by jmeter. ELB returns IPs of additional servers depending on how autoscaling is set but JMeter does not use these additional servers. This problem can be solved by ensuring that Jmeter does not cache DNS results...

The ELB is a name, not IP, and can suffer from DNS caching. Make sure you use "-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0" when starting JMeter

http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterAndAmazon

Answer (score 0):

A really late response, and slightly different than the original question, but I hope this can help others as it took me a while to get it all straight.  My original problem was not reduced throughput as a result of the ELB, but the introduction of HTTP 503 errors.  Actually, the ELB increased my throughput as compared to querying the web application directly, though even with 1 hour tests, the results were sporadic to say the least.

First, the ELB has 2-staged load balancing going on.  The first load balance is across the ELB's themselves.  That's done by associating multiple IP addresses to the hostname provided by AWS for the ELB you provision.  The second is then, of course, across your application instances behind the ELB.

Without trying to offend the SO gods, this is a really helpful article.

https://blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps

The most helpful information in there was to use the DNS Cache Manager module in JMeter.  This will query multiple DNS servers, and wipe out your DNS cache.

I implemented that module and then setup Wireshark, filtering on the two IP addresses belonging to the ELB hostname and sure enough, it was querying both IP addresses, though clearly favored one over the other.

That didn't make a big difference, at least not over short tests.

The real difference (2-3 times more throughput) came when I tweaked the ELB health settings.  I initially had a high error rate, however after reducing the unhealthy threshold and the interval between health checks, my error rates dropped dramatically.

Additionally, whereas all my other tests had been 60 - 90 minutes in duration, this one was 8 hours.  I started out with decent throughput and it then quickly dropped (by about 2/3).  After about 20 minutes or more, the throughput then started ticking back up and by the end of the test, it had sustained throughput of about 5 times what I was getting without the ELB (which was similar to what the throughput was when it dropped shortly after beginning this test).